# java.io.IOException,Forbidden exception when running graph in CloudConnect

Tags: java, clover, gooddata

When I run an etl graph in CloudConnect a get this type of warning/error messages:

`INFO  [WEB_DAV_SOURCE_FILE_LIST_0] - Retrying task=com.gooddata.clover.plugin.file.manipulator.AbstractFileManipulator$CheckExistence, attempt=1, waitTime=1000, reason=java.io.IOException,Forbidden
INFO  [WEB_DAV_SOURCE_FILE_LIST_0] - Retrying task=com.gooddata.clover.plugin.file.manipulator.AbstractFileManipulator$CheckExistence, attempt=2, waitTime=2000, reason=java.io.IOException,Forbidden
INFO  [WEB_DAV_SOURCE_FILE_LIST_0] - Retrying task=com.gooddata.clover.plugin.file.manipulator.AbstractFileManipulator$CheckExistence, attempt=3, waitTime=4000, reason=java.io.IOException,Forbidden`

someone has any idea what can cause it? 
it is raised from FileList component when connecting to project storage.

Answer (score 1):

I think that some of these parameters are wrong:

- GDC_PROJECT_ID
- GDC_USERNAME
- GDC_PASSWORD

Or maybe the path to webdav is wrong

- use na1-di.gooddata.com instead of secure-di.gooddata.com

If this does not work, please provide more information here.

Answer (score 1):

Also, please ensure that the `GDC_USERNAME` and `GDC_PASSWORD` parameters are URL encoded.  This is a simple URL encoding helper:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

`user@email.com` becomes: `user%40email.com`